# Integration of $3x^2ydx+x^3dy$ by two methods

Tags: integration, derivatives, solution-verification

> Find $\int(3x^2ydx+x^3dy)$

$\int(3x^2ydx+x^3dy)=\int d(x^3y)=x^3y+c$

Or, $\int(3x^2ydx+x^3dy)=\int3x^2ydx+\int x^3dy=x^3y+x^3y+c=2x^3y+c$

Why am I getting different answers from the two methods?

I am certain that the first method is correct.

About the second, I took one variable as constant while integrating. Is this wrong? Is this leading to the wrong answer? If yes, how to get the correct answer from this method? i.e. without the exact differential form, can we integrate to get the answer?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** With the help of the comments, I am able to do this now:

$\int(3x^2ydx+x^3dy)=\int3x^2ydx+\int x^3dy=x^3y+f(y)+x^3y+g(x)$

Can you guide how to proceed next? Thanks.

Comment: The $c$ that you put must  two functions $f(y)$ and $g(x)$ since you have  two integrals respect to $x$ and $y$ respectively.

Comment: @BrienNavarro Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: If x is not constant How can you bring it out

Comment: @LalitTolani when it's $dy$, I am taking $x$ as constant. When it's $dx$, I am taking $y$ as constant. Is it wrong?

Comment: Does it provides you any hint that x is constant when we consider dy

Comment: When you integrate a function $f(x,y)$ respect to $x$ your constant of integration should be a function $g(y)$ and similarly if you integrate with respect to $y$ you should get a constant of integration a function $h(x)$.

Comment: @BrienNavarro Thanks. I'll try in this direction now.

Comment: @LalitTolani Thanks. Brien explained that to me.

Comment: @BrienNavarro I have made an edit. Can you check please?

Comment: @LalitTolani I have made an edit. Can you check please?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you're asking what's wrong with this (obviously wrong) “identity:”
$$\color{red}{
    f = \int df = \int \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,dy\right) = \int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dx + \int \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,dy = f + f = 2f
}$$

I think it's in the step where you identify $\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dx  = f$.  Consider a curve $C$ parametrized by $(x(t),y(t))$ over an interval $a \leq t \leq b$.  Then
\begin{align*}
    \int_C \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dx
    &= \int_a^b \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x(t),y(t))x'(t)\,dt
\end{align*}
We can't integrate this to $\left.f(x(t),y(t))\right|^b_a$ unless $y'(t) = 0$.

On the other hand, we can substitute for $C$ an L-shaped path $C_1+C_2$, where $C_1$ is the horizontal line from $(x(a),y(a))$ to $(x(b),y(a))$, and $C_2$ is the vertical line from $(x(b),y(a))$ to $(x(b),y(b))$.
\begin{align*}
    \int_{C_1} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dx
    &= \int_a^b f(x(t),y(a))x'(t)\,dt 
    \\&= f(x(b),y(a)) - f(x(a),y(a))
    \\\int_{C_2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,dx
    &= \int_a^b f(x(b),y(t))y'(t)\,dt 
    \\&= f(x(b),y(b)) - f(x(b),y(a))
\end{align*}
The two of these add up to $f(x(b),y(b)) - f(x(a),y(a)) = \int_C df$.